# Cannot access IIS on Windows 7

Tags: iis-7.5

I created a website on my dev machine (Windows 7 RC) and am able to access it from http://localhost/ or http://172.16.0.140/ (my IP) or http://seven/ (computer name).

I can ping my machine from other computer but I can't access the site from other computer.

**"the webpage is not available"**

do you have any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked your firewall on the computer 'Seven' ? it needs to have port 80 (or whatever port the default website) open for TCP.

Do you know how to do that? if no, ask here and we'll provide more info.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, when I turned off the Windows firewall, it's working, so it must have something to do with the firewall.  I turned the firewall back on and create new rule to allow inbound/outbound traffic for port 80 only from any address without authentication, and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If the firewall is open to port 80 on the server, are you sure the web service is running? Or that the page is actually there? It may be telling you that the web server isn't running or the page doesn't exist.

Are there any messages in the application or system log that clue in what's happening?